# Jquery event to check the text box value changed or not

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery.....I want to change the `window.thisPage.isDirty = false` to `true` whenever there is change in the text box value for that I have used

```
$('#inputId').keyup(function () { window.thisPage.isDirty = true });
```

but it is not working for me i have tried also

```
$('#inputId').on('input',function () { window.thisPage.isDirty = true });
```

which is not working for me Please suggest.

Comment: you can add the class to input textbox when value is changed. For .eg             $('#inputId').keyup(function () { $(this).addClass('input-changed'); });

Answer (score 0):

You must define `window.thisPage`

```js
window.thisPage={isDirty: false}
$("#value").off("keyup").on("keyup",function(){
  window.thisPage.isDirty = true
   $("#text").html(window.thisPage.isDirty)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="value"/>
<span id="text"></span>
```